# jQuery Detect Web Page Height Instead of Window Height

Tags: jquery

The following line: "$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);" makes a button visible after scrolling 900 or more screen lines. However, it is based on the window height of 800 Pixels and not the document height of about 3500 pixels. On a screen with a window height of 800 pixels, it executes to soon since I am not detecting the document height instead. Is there away to detect the **document height** instead of the window height?

I've search here and did not find anything that was helpful but, being new I may have overlooked something in ignorance. My apology if I have.

I have also found several calls for document height and ways to parse the document height into a variable. None of these methods worked for me as I may be missing something else as well.

I am assuming the code below is the call for making my button visible at the screen line of 900.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var self = $(this),
           height = self.height(),
           top = self.scrollTop();
           if(top > height) {
         if(!totop.is(':visible')) {
           totop.fadeIn("slow");
        }
          } else {
        totop.hide();
      }
  });
});
```

I changed window to document with no luck. I tried many other options too with no luck. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks. PS Sorry, I can't figure out the "Code" thing on the editor. Not user friendly to newbies.

Comment: try `document.body.scrollHeight` [Element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight)

Comment: I revisited this solution for the 3rd time with no luck. If it works, it does not work in my script and ther4e are not to many places to put it. I even tried to implement it as a single line of code too with no luck.

Comment: I may not have clear. The "Turn-On" screen line is 100 pixels beyond my window size of 800 pixels. My web page is even longer. I want my button to turn on at line 900 and beyond when I scroll the page that far. So far, I am restricted to the widow and not the web page. (document) Maybe this makes my mission more clear. Thanks for your help regardless of my outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem!

I changed this line from **"$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);"** to **"$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});"**. I then modified this line from **if(top > height) {** to **if(top > 900) {**. This causes my back to top button to appear on or after the screen line 900 when I scroll past it. The script also scrolls to the very top when my button is clicked.

Thanks for all who considered this problem for a solution!